# How do I create a Twitter status update in JavaScript and also receive a response from it?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am searching for a way to trigger a custom Twitter Status update in JavaScript similar to how you can share on Facebook from pure JavaScript:

```
fb.ui({object to share}, function(response){//do stuff});
```

So far all I seem to find are examples that include launching a Twitter Status update from a DOM element without a callback of any kind. For my implementation, it is very important that I know that the Twitter status update was successful (`HTTP 200`).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca do a simple ajax GET request on i.e. `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Maybe%20he%27ll%20finally%20find%20his%20keys.%20%23peterfalk`

and then check the HTTP result of the ajax request. The request needs an oAuth access token and needs to be signed, look [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update)

Probably there's no out-of-the-box solution but it should be quite easy to type these few lines.

Comment: Thanks you very much!